# PostgreSQL : evaluate a substring inside function

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I am trying to extract the left part of an `email` field based on the separator `@`.

For instance, from the following email: `root@localhost` I want to extract `root`.

I wrote:

```
select email, substr(email,1,strpos(email, '@')-1)
from user;
```

but I get:

```
[22011] ERROR: negative substring length not allowed
```

How can I make the substring inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `strpos` function but didn't find the character in the string.

I would use [POSITION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function to get charter position and do substring to get the value, because if it didn't find character will return `0` instead of an error.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   email varchar(50)
);

insert into t values ('aa@gmmail.com');
insert into t values ('11.com');
insert into t values ('test@gmmail.com');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select CASE WHEN POSITION('@' in email) > 0 THEN 
                 substr(email,1,POSITION('@' in email)-1)
            ELSE ''
            END
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8c547f/1/0)**:

```
| case |
|------|
|   aa |
|      |
| test |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well for valid email addresses. But if you don't have any `@` chars in your strings it fails.

So you might have invalid email addresses in your table.

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d504ede59e2bef6d8435c93440d51e29)

Comment: you are right! some rows contains invalid email which explain that error! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this just by adding a `@` to the end:

```
select email, substr(email, 1, strpos(email || '@', '@') - 1)
from user;
```

Or one of these alternatives:

```
select email, left(email, strpos(email || '@', '@') - 1)

select email, substring(email from '^[^@]*')
```